# Why does the Star-5A have such a bad mass ratio?

Tags: solid-fuel, mass-fraction

I went over the KSP-RO's Discord research notes and found this PDF about the Star kick motors.  The OP wrote that the Star-5A had a mass ratio of 0.493, which seems extremely low from a solid motor standpoint.  Is there any reason why it doesn't contain as much propellant than any other solid motor?

[image]

Comment: Comment instead of answer because I'm not a mechanical engineer, but the Star-5A is extremely small, at 4.6kg. At that size, the usual observed scaling relationships for larger rockets don't apply -- in short, the proportional contribution of the metal casing to the total mass is much higher than it would be for a multi-ton motor.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - sounds like a answer! OP - do you have a link to the source of the graphic? You described it verbally, but that meant nothing to me.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Or, in other words: the square-cube law works in both directions!